# Display user bio in a column on Woocommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

We store some customer info in his/her Bio text area in user edit page.
How to display this stored data in user Bio field as a column in the Order admin page in woocommerce ?
I tried this code but its not working:

```
// Adding a custom new column to admin orders list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_column_eldest_players', 20 );
function custom_column_eldest_players($columns)
{
    $reordered_columns = array();

    // Inserting columns to a specific location
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            // Inserting after "Status" column
            $reordered_columns['skb-client'] = __( 'Oudste Speler','theme_domain');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Adding custom fields meta data for the column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
    if ( 'skb-client' != $column ) return;

    global $the_order;

    // Get the customer Bio
    $user_bio = get_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'description', true );


        $user_data = get_userdata( $user_bio );
        echo $user_data->user_bio; // The WordPress user name

}
```

we need this stored data to displayed for each costumers purchase.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$order` is not defined in your 2nd function, so you need to use instead `$the_order`. then I have revisited you code… Try the following instead:

```
 // Adding a custom new column to admin orders list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_column_eldest_players', 20 );
function custom_column_eldest_players($columns)
{
    $reordered_columns = array();

    // Inserting columns to a specific location
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            // Inserting after "Status" column
            $reordered_columns['user-bio'] = __( 'User bio', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Adding custom fields meta data for the column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'user-bio' === $column ) {
        global $the_order;

        echo ( $user = $the_order->get_user() ) ? $user->description : 'n/c';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: I'm using Admin Columns Pro. How can enable inline edit for this column in woocommerce orders admin page?